# My battery drains really fast and my laptop gets really hot, What do I do?

Tags: laptop, hp, battery, overheating

I just installed Ubuntu on my HP Pavilion dv6-6c50ca, and I noticed that every time that I start my laptop with Ubuntu the fan runs really fast and the laptop produces a lot of heat. When I run windows on it, the battery life lasts for 4 hours but when I run Ubuntu, it barely lasts for an hour and a half no matter what I'm doing, even when I'm typing a simple word document. Here are my laptop specifications:

- HD BrightView LED-backlit Display
- Intel core i5 2.5 Ghz i5-2450M
- 750GB hard drive 5400RPM
- Video card: AMD Radeon HD 7690M XT
- Battery: 6-Cell Lithium-ion

[Here is a more detailed specification in case I left out anything important](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/searchtools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=1917488&cm_mmc=Email-_-WebletMain-_-CANLET-_-03ship&SRCCODE=CANLET).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what kernel version do you use? can you give some detail about it?
uname -a; cat /etc/lsb-release

Comment: Do you use the proprietary ATI drivers?

Comment: Here's what showed up when I typed in that command:
tedderic@ubuntu:~$ uname -a; cat/etc/lsb-release
Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
bash: cat/etc/lsb-release: No such file or directory

Comment: And yes I'm using the 3D-accelerated proprietary graphics driver for ATI cards.

Comment: Still having this problem? Have you tried a newer version of Ubuntu?